# Session persistence issue with Hazelcast, Jetty and Nginx

Tags: session, nginx, persistence, jetty, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast as a webapp session storage for Jetty instances. There is also Nginx in front of the Jetty instances as a load balancer.

**Problem:**
Session sharing works out perfect as two of my jetty servers work side by side on different ports (8080 and 8081). However, when I restart one single Jetty instance (8081), I lose my shared session.
I use default hazelcast.xml and filters, jars were put correctly into the webapp as well.

Here is the example of the groovy-grails webapp code that employs the session object:

```
package jtest

class HomeController {

def index() {
if(!session.test){
session.test = 1
} else {
session.test++
}
render "port = " + request.getServerPort() + "; session = " + session.test 
}
}
```

The **nginx.conf** file contains the following lines:

```
upstream backend  {
    #ip_hash;
server 127.0.0.1:8081; # Reverse proxy to  BES1
server 127.0.0.1:8082; # Reverse proxy to  BES2
}

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
location / {
    proxy_pass              http://backend;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
}
```

**Question:**
Actually, I would like to enquire if this situation is normal or there is anything special to mention about the settings?

Here are the **code samples**:

http://snipt.org/ziBa8 - **Hazelcast.xml** (left almost intact)
http://snipt.org/ziBb2 - Hazelcast filters code from the webapp **/WEB-INF/web.xml**

Comment: can you share your code & config for session storage?

Comment: sure. i've just updated the links